# Bitcoins Stuck?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, mtgox, bter

This morning I attempted to send BTC to my Bter account from my Mt Gox account. I sent them and they seemed to reappear. I sent them again and there was a little left over, I sent that. Now the smaller amount went through but the larger amount never got there. Here are the links [(1)](https://blockchain.info/address/13RcWHLciYf5gdaEQ2hjELmzJvBuHEbwdb) and [(2)](http://blockexplorer.com/address/13RcWHLciYf5gdaEQ2hjELmzJvBuHEbwdb) in blockchain.

Here is my wallet address: `13RcWHLciYf5gdaEQ2hjELmzJvBuHEbwdb`

I can get no reply from Bter or Mt Gox. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: The time stamp on the larger transaction is 3 hours earlier. This is impossible. I moved them all within 5 minutes.

Comment: Transaction timestamps don't really mean anything. Lots of different things happen to transactions at different times, and sometimes at different times in different places. They are first seen, relayed, get into a block, the block gets confirmations, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

My bet is that your bitcoin-qt client is not fully synced or maybe you haven't received enough confirmations on your transactions. Bitcoin transactions can unfortunately move slow. Larger transactions have this 'transaction fee' that is often requested.

Comment: It was not in my client. It was supposed to go from Mt Gox to Bter. Two different sites. My client wasn't involved.

Comment: Thank you for the reply though....I'm a a complete loss. I'm a huge fan of Bitcoin and this shakes my confidence. It's Mt Gox that screwed up the send or maybe I just have to wait. It's just hard not having any recourse when these things happen.

Comment: Why your confidence *in Bitcoin*? Do you have a transaction that unconfirmed or something like that?

Comment: It's confirmed it just says $0 and I sent 0.09759485. How does it just disappear in transit. Look at the blockchain. It says sent, then $0....I don't get it. http://blockexplorer.com/address/13RcWHLciYf5gdaEQ2hjELmzJvBuHEbwdb

Comment: You received 0.09759485 BTC and then sent them. The link you sent shows all four transactions.

Comment: I didn't receive anything. I converted some USD into BTC on MT gox and attempted to send it to my accounnt on Bter. Supposedly when you send BTC it come back to you and then goes out....I'm not sure but I think I sent it twice somehow...like a double spend....The Mt Gox software screwed up and I wound up re-sending my coin. I've heard back from others that the Mt Gox site has been a lot of trouble for a lot of people.Again.....I did not receive anything just converted and sent....$0 arrived. Not my day.